# Multiply the values for each row in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, genetic-algorithm

I'm building genetic algorithm to feature selection in python. I have extracted features from my datas, then I divided into two dataframe, 'train' and 'test' dataframe.
How can I multiple the values for each row in 'population' dataframe (each individu) and 'train' dataframe?

'train' dataframe:

```
   feature0   feature1   feature2   feature3   feature4   feature5
0  18.279579  -3.921346  13.611829  -7.250185 -11.773605 -18.265003   
1  17.899545 -15.503942  -0.741729  -0.053619  -6.734652   4.398419   
4  16.432750 -22.490190  -4.611659 -15.247781 -13.941488  -2.433374   
5  15.905368  -4.812785  18.291712   3.742221   3.631887  -1.074326   
6  16.991823 -15.946251   8.299577   8.057511   8.057510  -1.482333
```

'population' dataframe:

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5     
0     1     1     0     0     0     1     
1     0     1     0     1     0     0     
2     0     0     0     0     0     1     
3     0     0     1     0     1     1
```

Multiplying each row in 'population' to all rows in 'train'.
It will results:

1) From population row 1:

```
   feature0   feature1   feature2   feature3   feature4   feature5
0  18.279579  -3.921346          0          0          0 -18.265003   
1  17.899545 -15.503942          0          0          0   4.398419   
4  16.432750 -22.490190          0          0          0  -2.433374   
5  15.905368  -4.812785          0          0          0  -1.074326   
6  16.991823 -15.946251          0          0          0  -1.482333
```

2) From population row 2:

```
   feature0   feature1   feature2   feature3   feature4   feature5
0          0  -3.921346          0  -7.250185          0          0
1          0 -15.503942          0  -0.053619          0          0   
4          0 -22.490190          0 -15.247781          0          0   
5          0  -4.812785          0   3.742221          0          0   
6          0 -15.946251          0   8.057511          0          0
```

And so on...

Answer (score 4):

If need loop (slow if large data):

```
for i, x in population.iterrows():
    print (train * x.values)

    feature0   feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4   feature5
0  18.279579  -3.921346       0.0      -0.0      -0.0 -18.265003
1  17.899545 -15.503942      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   4.398419
4  16.432750 -22.490190      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0  -2.433374
5  15.905368  -4.812785       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.074326
6  16.991823 -15.946251       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.482333
   feature0   feature1  feature2   feature3  feature4  feature5
0       0.0  -3.921346       0.0  -7.250185      -0.0      -0.0
1       0.0 -15.503942      -0.0  -0.053619      -0.0       0.0
4       0.0 -22.490190      -0.0 -15.247781      -0.0      -0.0
5       0.0  -4.812785       0.0   3.742221       0.0      -0.0
6       0.0 -15.946251       0.0   8.057511       0.0      -0.0
   feature0  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4   feature5
0       0.0      -0.0       0.0      -0.0      -0.0 -18.265003
1       0.0      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   4.398419
4       0.0      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0  -2.433374
5       0.0      -0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.074326
6       0.0      -0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.482333
   feature0  feature1   feature2  feature3   feature4   feature5
0       0.0      -0.0  13.611829      -0.0 -11.773605 -18.265003
1       0.0      -0.0  -0.741729      -0.0  -6.734652   4.398419
4       0.0      -0.0  -4.611659      -0.0 -13.941488  -2.433374
5       0.0      -0.0  18.291712       0.0   3.631887  -1.074326
6       0.0      -0.0   8.299577       0.0   8.057510  -1.482333
```

---

Or each row separately:

```
print (train * population.values[0])

    feature0   feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4   feature5
0  18.279579  -3.921346       0.0      -0.0      -0.0 -18.265003
1  17.899545 -15.503942      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   4.398419
4  16.432750 -22.490190      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0  -2.433374
5  15.905368  -4.812785       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.074326
6  16.991823 -15.946251       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.482333
```

---

Or for MultiIndex DataFrame:

```
d = pd.concat([train * population.values[i] for i in range(population.shape[0])],
               keys=population.index.tolist())
print (d)

      feature0   feature1   feature2   feature3   feature4   feature5
0 0  18.279579  -3.921346   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000 -18.265003
  1  17.899545 -15.503942  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   4.398419
  4  16.432750 -22.490190  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -2.433374
  5  15.905368  -4.812785   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.074326
  6  16.991823 -15.946251   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.482333
1 0   0.000000  -3.921346   0.000000  -7.250185  -0.000000  -0.000000
  1   0.000000 -15.503942  -0.000000  -0.053619  -0.000000   0.000000
  4   0.000000 -22.490190  -0.000000 -15.247781  -0.000000  -0.000000
  5   0.000000  -4.812785   0.000000   3.742221   0.000000  -0.000000
  6   0.000000 -15.946251   0.000000   8.057511   0.000000  -0.000000
2 0   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000 -18.265003
  1   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   4.398419
  4   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -2.433374
  5   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.074326
  6   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.482333
3 0   0.000000  -0.000000  13.611829  -0.000000 -11.773605 -18.265003
  1   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.741729  -0.000000  -6.734652   4.398419
  4   0.000000  -0.000000  -4.611659  -0.000000 -13.941488  -2.433374
  5   0.000000  -0.000000  18.291712   0.000000   3.631887  -1.074326
  6   0.000000  -0.000000   8.299577   0.000000   8.057510  -1.482333
```

And select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (d.xs(0))

    feature0   feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4   feature5
0  18.279579  -3.921346       0.0      -0.0      -0.0 -18.265003
1  17.899545 -15.503942      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   4.398419
4  16.432750 -22.490190      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0  -2.433374
5  15.905368  -4.812785       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.074326
6  16.991823 -15.946251       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.482333
```

Comment: @piRSquared I added way to do the MI without a list comprehension. Though I suspect performance isn't really an issue here :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use numpy broadcasting to do it all in one go...

```
train_ = pd.DataFrame(
    (train.values * pop.values[:, None]).reshape(-1, train.shape[1]),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pop.index, train.index]),
    train.columns
)

train_

      feature0   feature1   feature2   feature3   feature4   feature5
0 0  18.279579  -3.921346   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000 -18.265003
  1  17.899545 -15.503942  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   4.398419
  4  16.432750 -22.490190  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -2.433374
  5  15.905368  -4.812785   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.074326
  6  16.991823 -15.946251   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.482333
1 0   0.000000  -3.921346   0.000000  -7.250185  -0.000000  -0.000000
  1   0.000000 -15.503942  -0.000000  -0.053619  -0.000000   0.000000
  4   0.000000 -22.490190  -0.000000 -15.247781  -0.000000  -0.000000
  5   0.000000  -4.812785   0.000000   3.742221   0.000000  -0.000000
  6   0.000000 -15.946251   0.000000   8.057511   0.000000  -0.000000
2 0   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000 -18.265003
  1   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   4.398419
  4   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -2.433374
  5   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.074326
  6   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.482333
3 0   0.000000  -0.000000  13.611829  -0.000000 -11.773605 -18.265003
  1   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.741729  -0.000000  -6.734652   4.398419
  4   0.000000  -0.000000  -4.611659  -0.000000 -13.941488  -2.433374
  5   0.000000  -0.000000  18.291712   0.000000   3.631887  -1.074326
  6   0.000000  -0.000000   8.299577   0.000000   8.057510  -1.482333
```

You can access just the one corresponding to the ith row or `population` with `train_.loc[i]`

```
train_.loc[3]

   feature0  feature1   feature2  feature3   feature4   feature5
0       0.0      -0.0  13.611829      -0.0 -11.773605 -18.265003
1       0.0      -0.0  -0.741729      -0.0  -6.734652   4.398419
4       0.0      -0.0  -4.611659      -0.0 -13.941488  -2.433374
5       0.0      -0.0  18.291712       0.0   3.631887  -1.074326
6       0.0      -0.0   8.299577       0.0   8.057510  -1.482333
```

---

**ROUGH TIME TEST**
*I'm too lazy to do more robust testing*

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(
    (train.values * pop.values[:, None]).reshape(-1, train.shape[1]),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pop.index, train.index]),
    train.columns
)

%%timeit
res = pop.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(pop)), len(train))]
res = res.set_index(np.tile(train.index, len(pop)), append=True).add_prefix('feature')
res.mul(train, level=1)

%%timeit
pd.concat([train * pop.values[i] for i in range(pop.shape[0])],
               keys=pop.index.tolist())

571 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.42 ms ± 18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.7 ms ± 69.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the columns of `population` to match `train` you can use `*`:

```
In [11]: population.columns = train.columns

In [12]: train * population.iloc[0]
Out[12]:
    feature0   feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4   feature5
0  18.279579  -3.921346       0.0      -0.0      -0.0 -18.265003
1  17.899545 -15.503942      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0   4.398419
4  16.432750 -22.490190      -0.0      -0.0      -0.0  -2.433374
5  15.905368  -4.812785       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.074326
6  16.991823 -15.946251       0.0       0.0       0.0  -1.482333
```

---

You can make a MultiIndex (as recommended by @jezrael) very efficiently using `np.tile` and `np.repeat`:

```
In [11]: res = population.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(population)), len(train))]

In [12]: res = res.set_index(np.tile(train.index, len(population)), append=True)

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
     feature0  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4  feature5
0 0         1         1         0         0         0         1
  1         1         1         0         0         0         1
  4         1         1         0         0         0         1
  5         1         1         0         0         0         1
  6         1         1         0         0         0         1
1 0         0         1         0         1         0         0
  1         0         1         0         1         0         0
  4         0         1         0         1         0         0
  5         0         1         0         1         0         0
  6         0         1         0         1         0         0
2 0         0         0         0         0         0         1
  1         0         0         0         0         0         1
  4         0         0         0         0         0         1
  5         0         0         0         0         0         1
  6         0         0         0         0         0         1
3 0         0         0         1         0         1         1
  1         0         0         1         0         1         1
  4         0         0         1         0         1         1
  5         0         0         1         0         1         1
  6         0         0         1         0         1         1

In [14]: res.mul(train, level=1)
Out[14]:
      feature0   feature1   feature2   feature3   feature4   feature5
0 0  18.279579  -3.921346   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000 -18.265003
  1  17.899545 -15.503942  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   4.398419
  4  16.432750 -22.490190  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -2.433374
  5  15.905368  -4.812785   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.074326
  6  16.991823 -15.946251   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.482333
1 0   0.000000  -3.921346   0.000000  -7.250185  -0.000000  -0.000000
  1   0.000000 -15.503942  -0.000000  -0.053619  -0.000000   0.000000
  4   0.000000 -22.490190  -0.000000 -15.247781  -0.000000  -0.000000
  5   0.000000  -4.812785   0.000000   3.742221   0.000000  -0.000000
  6   0.000000 -15.946251   0.000000   8.057511   0.000000  -0.000000
2 0   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000 -18.265003
  1   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000   4.398419
  4   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -0.000000  -2.433374
  5   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.074326
  6   0.000000  -0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  -1.482333
3 0   0.000000  -0.000000  13.611829  -0.000000 -11.773605 -18.265003
  1   0.000000  -0.000000  -0.741729  -0.000000  -6.734652   4.398419
  4   0.000000  -0.000000  -4.611659  -0.000000 -13.941488  -2.433374
  5   0.000000  -0.000000  18.291712   0.000000   3.631887  -1.074326
  6   0.000000  -0.000000   8.299577   0.000000   8.057510  -1.482333
```

Comment: PlusOned from the beginning (-: I use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`. and a reshape on the value multiplication.  So I'm only constructing one dataframe and one MultiIndex.  I'll test performance for kicks.  If you look at my edits or timeline, you'll notice that my first answer was `pd.concat` with `keys=pop.index.tolist()`

Comment: @piRSquared of course, from_product (I wrote cartesian_product so should remember it's existence) :)